# Why is my SQL procedure returning the entire table?

Tags: mysql, procedures

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS STUDENTS_BY_STATUS;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE STUDENTS_BY_STATUS(status VARCHAR(10))

BEGIN

    SELECT BannerId, Name FROM STUDENT WHERE Status=status;

END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL STUDENTS_BY_STATUS("Freshman");
```

My Table (STUDENT)
[image]

My Result

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call your parameter with some other name as you have column named status in your table.

I usually follow the convention of `p_` prefix for parameters and `v_` for local variables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE STUDENTS_BY_STATUS(p_status VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN    
    SELECT BannerId, Name FROM STUDENT WHERE Status = p_status;
END //
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'm not quite sure why my professor asked us to have the parameter as status even though he must know this conflict.

Comment: @KyleJ - May be he was testing you. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS STUDENTS_BY_STATUS;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE STUDENTS_BY_STATUS(IN statusIn VARCHAR(10))

BEGIN

    SELECT BannerId, Name FROM STUDENT WHERE Status=statusIn;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Mark it as IN param and use diffrent name for param.

Comment: It's by default `IN`. There is no need to specify it explicitly